# How do I use TFSSecurity.exe to add users to administrator group on Team Foundation Server team project?

Tags: tfs

Suppose I have a team foundation server http://tfs:8080 and a collection named Collection1 and a project named Project1. How would I go about giving user User1 all privileges on the project? (Either by adding him to the Team Project Administrators group OR by granting individual privileges as you would in the GUI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i would recommend, download the TFS ADMIN tool http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/, this is a community tool that for TFS Administrators, The TFS Administration Tool allows Team Foundation Server administrators to manage user permissions on all three platforms utilized by Team Foundation Server: Team Foundation Server, SharePoint, and SQL Server Reporting Services. The tool also allows administrators to easily copy user permissions among team projects and to easily identify any missing permissions on any of the three platforms.

However, you don't need the admin tool to assign permissions. You can right click on the team project and click on group membership, double click on the group that you would like to add the user to and add their windows login to the group. You can read more about this here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477.aspx

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Hi Tarun, Thanks for the recommendation. I was looking for a way to use the command line so I could make my own TFSAdmin like tool but I will give it a whirl!

Comment: Hi Justin, o sorry, the command line script is, 
c:\projects>tf permission /group:[teamproject]\developers /collection: http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ If you go to visual studio command line and type tf.exe permission /? you can see the entire help text. HTH.

Comment: Also, the tool TFSAdmin has been build using the TFS API. You can get started using the TFS API, i have some getting stared posts on my blog http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx

Comment: Reference to TFS Command Line command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dsd05ft.aspx

Comment: The tool does not recognize Groups, only individual users.  Pretty much useless to me.